# Installing SDL game in Ubuntu

Tags: games, sdl

I'm trying to install 2Pong on Ubuntu for doing an experiment but I cannot figure out how to get it running. I installed all the requirements and followed the instructions in the README file but after many searches I still can't find a solution.

I also tried to follow the SDL instructions on their website but without success.

The README states:

> Requirements:
>
> - SDL
> - SDL_Net
> - SDL_Mixer
> - iconv
> - zlib
> - libxml2
>
> Compiling:
>
> - cd src
> - make

I installed everything but when I try to execute:

```
sudo make src
```

I get:

```
make: Nothing to be done for 'src'.
```

The files in the folder are: 2Pong, src(folder), README and conf.xml.

Link to the game:

http://twopong.sourceforge.net/

EDIT:
My error after implementing SurvivalMachine's fix:

```
In file included from net.cpp:1:0:
net.h:5:10: fatal error: SDL/SDL_net.h: No such file or directory
 #include <SDL/SDL_net.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
Makefile:52: recipe for target 'net.o' failed
make: *** [net.o] Error 1
```

Comment: I added a fix for the SDL_net error, but here's it again: sudo apt install libsdl1.2-dev libsdl-net1.2-dev libsdl-mixer1.2-dev libxml2-dev

Comment: Ok finally got it working thank you a ton! Would never have been able to do it without your help!

Comment: @SurvivalMachine You should post that comment as an answer.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia I already added the command into my answer before posting the comment.

Comment: @SurvivalMachine Sorry for bothering. This question came under review and I didn't notice you had already posted an answer. +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This step is wrong:

```
sudo make src
```

Instead you should go into src and run make:

```
cd src
make
```

To get correct dependencies, run these commands:

```
sudo apt install libsdl1.2-dev libsdl-net1.2-dev libsdl-mixer1.2-dev libxml2-dev
```

It looks like it's configured to compile as 32-bit application, so to compile on modern systems edit Makefile and remove `-march=i486 -mcpu=i686` from CFLAGS and CXXFLAGS.

There is also some code that does not compile without modifications. Open defs.h and find these lines:

```
rectangle defines::UpperBound();
rectangle defines::LowerBound();
rectangle defines::RightBound();
rectangle defines::LeftBound();
```

Remove `defines::` so it looks like this:

```
rectangle UpperBound();
rectangle LowerBound();
rectangle RightBound();
rectangle LeftBound();
```

Comment: I tried that before but i get: make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop.

Comment: I just downloaded it and src directory does contain Makefile. You must be running make from some other directory.

Comment: @Max did you download 2pong-src-1.0.1a.tar.gz?

Comment: I extracted the tar.gz file to my Desktop and ran: ubuntu@ubuntu:~/Desktop/2Pong-Linux/src$ make

Is this correct?

Comment: @Max If you run `ls` in the directory and see a Makefile, then it is the correct directory.

Comment: I downloaded the source now instead of the linux binary and that does indeed contain the makefile but i get an error on executing it now.

/bin/sh: 1 : xml2-config: not found
cc1plus: error: CPU you selected does not support x86-64 instruction set
makefile:52: recipe for target 'defs.o' failed
make: *** [defs.o] Error 1

Comment: @Max I updated my answer to resolve issues I had when I tried to compile the code.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help already! I'm sorry to say I still get an error though :( . I edited my post with the message I get.